# Would a tagging "metonym" feature be overkill?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonym-process

There seems to be a fair number of tags which despite being quashed often re-appear on the "new" tags screen as if waiting for the day someone tags a post in which the context give's it's existence some  meaning...

This may not be the best example as it will arguably never have any taxonomic value but one that cropped up again today would be [val](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/val).  It can't be synonymised with [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/value) because that gets nuked and despite being frequently attached to [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) posts it gets rejected as a synonym as it's presumably too generic.

This seems to leave a repetitive void in the system where folks are editing questions just to remove the same tags time and time again.  Would it be useful if a tag could be declared a metonym for another so that when used in conjunction it gets automatically nullified without impeding on it's usefulness (potentially) elsewhere?

Comment: How often does a new question come up with the tag [tag:val]?

Comment: Well I edited 3 today with val attached but I think it's beside the point - it's just one of many and just seems wasteful of peoples time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there aren't too many questions with the tag, you can just retag all the questions and pray that no one asks an new question with that tag until 3AM UTC the next day. If that is the case, the tag will be removed from the system and only users with 1500 reputation can recreate the tag.

In the case of a tag which has quite a few questions, you can ask the community on Meta to help retag these questions and edit the tag wiki accordingly to disambiguate or discourage the use of this tag.

In extreme cases (thousands of posts and many new questions with this tag) you may consider asking a community manager or developer to burninate or blacklist the tag, which deletes the tag from all questions and if it is blacklisted, prevents the tag from being used again.

I don't think the problem is severe enough to warrant the addition of such functionality. If there is a issue with a specific tag, you're more than welcome to bring it up on Meta.

Answer (score 1):

If a tag keeps **reappearing** and it's a **bad tag**, you can ask for *blacklisting the tag*. If you ask for it I would agree wholeheartedly.

Comment: Blacklisting is a dev-only option and they only do so for tags that are *so horribly inappropriate* that there's no other choice.  They won't blacklist tags that are merely *bad* and recur often, like `value` and `server` and `visual` and `game` and `convert` and `app` and the other **255** tags I keep my eye on.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not! I find the tagging system, as well as the lexicographical analysis in general, of Stack Exchange to be one of the weakest and most frustrating aspects, and its a severe usability issue.

There should be no reason why 'value' gets categorically nuked, and it *should* associate with 'val'.

Drop 'val' into a [FrameNet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu) search and you'll see it can clearly distinguish from context:

https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/lu/lu8500.xml?mode=annotation
https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/lu/lu11868.xml?mode=annotation
https://framenet2.icsi.berkeley.edu/fnReports/data/lu/lu13424.xml?mode=annotation