# Simple tag hierarchy to aid in searching / browsing

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-hierarchy

Many tags have natural parent tags, in the sense that a question tagged A would almost always be of potential use to someone searching or browsing questions tagged B.

For example, all [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) questions are about [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows).  If I'm browsing the windows tag (looking for questions to answer) or doing a search filtered to the windows tag (looking for an existing answer to my problem) I probably want to see all winapi questions, whether or not they are also tagged windows.

I'm proposing a mechanism similar to the tag synonym functionality, but instead of the child tag automatically changing to the parent tag, the parent tag would be automatically added.  (Such automatic tags would have to not count towards the five-tag limit.)

Alternatively, searches for a parent tag, or browsing a parent tag, could automatically include all child tags.

While it is already possible to browse or search multiple tags at once, there are too many tags for one person (particularly a newcomer) to look through them all to find all the possible alternate tags he or she should be searching/browsing.

Support for multiple level hierarchies might be useful in some cases, but I think a single level would be sufficient if that would simplify implementation.

Comment: [A proposal for tag hierarchy on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45438)

Comment: I would implement it not as a hierarchy but a `tag` could have more parent, as a `to-many` relationship, what do you think? i.e. iOS8 could have a parent like 'iOS' but also a '2014' as it was published in 2014

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working with your example: WINE does provide the WINAPI for non-Windows environments.
So, if it is a [wine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wine) question, it can be a [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) question without being a [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) question. That is one of the reasons it is rejected, beside added complexity.

Anyway, tag hierarchies are an oft-proposed and rejected feature.
For details and discussion, look on MSE, for example:

[A proposal for tag hierarchy on Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so)
[Implicit tagging hierarchy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58073/implicit-tagging-hierarchy)
[Provide a virtual URL hierarchy for tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63057/provide-a-virtual-url-hierarchy-for-tags)
and [many others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=tag+hierarchy)

Also relevant are requests for [Metonyms](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252260/would-a-tagging-metonym-feature-be-overkill/255100#255100) and cleanup efforts for null-value-tags, which might sometime gain value (though unlikely), and why they are not simply blacklisted.

Comment: WINE is not, in my opinion, a sufficiently complete and accurate representation of the Windows API for it to make sense to tag WINE question as winapi.  In any case, the occasional misfire shouldn't cause too many problems as compared to the status quo.

Comment: I did of course search for similar proposals, but on the wrong site; forgot about the split.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: To expand on that first point: if a question applies to both WINE and to Windows, then it makes sense for it to be tagged windows, either explicitly or implicitly.  If it only applies to WINE and not to Windows, then it shouldn't be tagged winapi.

Comment: I never meant to imply that WINE was perfect. It cannot be, the WINAPI is a moving target. Even MS sometimes is less than perfect, especially on architecture boundaries. Doubly so when one considers all those back-compat hacks needed to support but-it-works (today!!) code-mongers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if there are programmers explicitly developing for WINE?  I always thought of it as more aimed at end-users.

Comment: I doubt there are any (outside the project itself and for the project of course). Imho it wouldn't be quite sane. Developing with clean running on WINE in mind, now that *is* laudable, quite beside the goal itself: It means one has to code cleanly, thus has a decent chance of running without hacks for decades and without MS leaning over backwards for you.