# Tag inheritance

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm a user that visits many sites of the Stack Exchange platform, but basically do the most on Stack Overflow. For the past 2-3 years I've studied on my own the Python programming language and I'm following the `Python`'s tag to listen questions for answer. If somebody doesn't know, Python language has twomain branches: version 2 (<strike>stable</strike> longterm) and version 3 (<strike>development</strike> current). Those tags (`python-2.x` and `python-3.x`) exists as well at SO, and I was wondering if there exists some way to listen questions for Python 2 & 3 by only favoriting just `Python` (sort of tag inheritance), because I can't view tagged questions of more than one tag at the same time (some are tagged `python`, some `python-2.x`, and some `python-3.x`). Does this mechanism exists or it'll be implemented? Thanks!

PS: I'm subscribed to all three tags.

The idea is to subscribe all three tags: Python2, Python3 and Python with one single subscription. Whenever you click a tag, you can view all questions tagged with that one, but you cannot do something like *show me all questions with tag Python2 OR Python3 OR Python*.

Comment: Python 3 is **not** a development branch. Python 3.5 is the current development line instead.

Comment: Tag-hierarchies are an oft-proposed and always-declined feature-request.

Comment: Now it is just a duplicate of [How do active answerers find questions to answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254592); see my answer there on how I follow much more than just 3 tags in one page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Your answer on the suggested post is excellent. It showed me many ways of digging SO (so +1 to that question & your answer). But I was also searching a feature like Deduplicator said: when subscribing, subscribe all descendants.

Comment: @SonicARG: there are no descendants however. That feature request has already been made and declined.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255245/simple-tag-hierarchy-to-aid-in-searching-browsing

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with the wildcard mechanism for favorites.  Just favorite `Python*`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the little chat we had with @Martijn Pieters and @Deduplicator at the question of this post I can reach these conclusions:

- Tag inheritance was proposed but always declined.
- Multiple tag search [can be performed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254603/1091677).
- Wildcard search tag is allowed.

Thanks to all who commented this question, all of your answers were useful. Closing and accepting.