# Relationship between tags?

Tags: feature-request

I often ask question about Apple's CloudKit technology i.e. nowadays about CKSubscription class. Usually I set as tag iOS, CloudKit, CKSubsription

I think in some case it would make sense if setting a tag would automatically include other tags. And also if smb list questions with iOS tag,  CKSubscription and CloudKit questions would automatically listed, even dow asker forget to set that tags.

And sometimes easier to discover a new techology, field, domain, if user can see which 'subtags' belong to it, if user can walk through the graph of tags and relationships.

Comment: I have no idea what CloudKit is but it seems extremely unlikely that every question related to an operating system would need it. Alif you make this suggestion I'd go the other way around; who decides the links though?

Comment: Q finetuned, higher then x reputation could create relationships

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255245/simple-tag-hierarchy-to-aid-in-searching-browsing

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262823/wouldnt-tag-inheritance-make-sense